# transforming one date string into another java

Tags: java, string, simpledateformat

I looked around here and could not find anything that matches what I need.

I get the following String:

```
"March 13, 2013"
```

and need to transform it into

```
"2013-03-13"
```

I tried using this code:

```
    SimpleDateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMMMMMMMM dd, YYYY");
    SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-dd");
    Date d = inputFormat.parse(startDate);
    System.out.println(outputFormat.format(d));
```

but i get "203-12-30".. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just copied and pasted your code made a few small changes and got the result you were looking for. The main change I made was changing the upper case "Y" in inputFormat and outputFormat to lower case "y". Anyway here you are:

```
String startDate = "March 13, 2013";
SimpleDateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMMMMMMMM dd, yyyy");
SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

try {
    Date d = inputFormat.parse(startDate);
    System.out.println(outputFormat.format(d));
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`Y` represents week year. Try using `y`

```
SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a try with the following code:

```
String startDate = "March 13, 2013";
    SimpleDateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd, yyyy",Locale.ENGLISH);
    SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    Date d = inputFormat.parse(startDate);
    System.out.println(outputFormat.format(d));
```